# How to sense highlighting in python

Tags: python, tkinter, text-editor

This is a theoretical question so please don't give me a piece of code. I was recently creating a text editor and I was thinking about if it was possible for my code sense a piece of text the user highlighted and give him an options menu. Is that possible?(btw I'm using TKinter)

Comment: I am also making a text editor in tkinter right now. It is possible to bind to the user selecting text and display options based on that. What do you actually want use to do? You specifically said that we shouldn't "don't give [you] a piece of code".

Comment: @TheLizzard Nothing I just wanted to see if it was possible and if you could recommend a source for m eto learn how to do it because I couldn't find anything online.

Comment: Ok. It is possible and there are a few sources. I am yet to find the full tkinter documentation but [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20201112023803/https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm) is good enough most of the time. For more in depth information I just use the [tcl documentation](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/text.htm)